# With VBA determine which option button in a grouped set is selected in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, radio-button, powerpoint

I've tried so many variations without success I have lost my brain. I need to set a group of variables based on which option button is selected within it's given group. There are 3 groups simply labeled OptionGroup1, OptionGroup2, & OptionGroup3. When the start button is executed I need to determine which options are selected and set the corresponding variables for use else where in the code. PowerPoint definitely is not the same as excel and I can't seem to get the right syntax for it. This particular attempt gives me "runtime error 438", "the object does not support this property or method"

```
Set myDocument = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)

Select Case myDocument.Shapes.GroupName = OptionGroup2
    
    Case Is = 1: ACLDelay = 1
    Case Is = 2: ACLDelay = 2
    Case Is = 3: ACLDelay = 3
    Case Is = 4: ACLDelay = Int((4 * Rnd) + 1)
    
End Select
    
Select Case myDocument.Shapes.GroupName = OptionGroup1

    Case Is = 1: RunInt = 15
    Case Is = 2: RunInt = 60
    Case Is = 3: RunInt = 30
    Case Is = 4: RunInt = 5
    
End Select

Select Case myDocument.Shapes.GroupName = OptionGroup1

    Case Is = 1: MODDelay = 1.5
    Case Is = 2: MODDelay = 1
    Case Is = 3: MODDelay = 2
    Case Is = 4: MODDelay = 0.5
    
End Select
```

Comment: You appear to be completely confused as to how to use the Select construct in VBA and also how to access buttons in an option group.  Perhaps if you could add an image of your form to your question things might be a little clearer.  It would also help if you listed the names of the buttons in each option group.

Comment: Can you better explain what you want accomplishing? `Shapes` property does not have a `GroupName` property. What 1 to 4 should mean in your code? Do the Option buttons have such names and does the code refer to them? Your approach is wrong, anyhow, but in order to be helped you need to make us understand what you want doing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next way. "Opt1", "Opt1" etc. should be the names of the option buttons (you may use their caption, too, but the code must be adapted):

```
Sub testOptButtGroupName()
   Dim ap As Presentation, sh As Shape, opB As MSForms.OptionButton
   Dim RunInt As Long, ACLDelay As Long 'you probably have to declare these variable at the module level
   Set ap = ActivePresentation
   For Each sh In ap.Slides(1).Shapes
        If sh.Type = msoOLEControlObject Then
            If TypeName(sh.OLEFormat.Object) = "OptionButton" Then
            Select Case sh.OLEFormat.Object.GroupName
                Case "OptionGroup1"
                    Select Case sh.Name
                        Case "Opt1"
                            If sh.OLEFormat.Object.Value = True Then RunInt = 15
                        Case "Opt2"
                             If sh.OLEFormat.Object.Value = True Then RunInt = 60
                             'and so on...
                    End Select
                Case "OptionGroup2"
                   Select Case sh.Name
                        Case "Opt5"
                            If sh.OLEFormat.Object.Value = True Then ACLDelay = 1
                        Case "Opt6"
                            If sh.OLEFormat.Object.Value = True Then ACLDelay = 2
                            'and so on...
                    End Select
                    'and so on...
            End Select
            End If
        End If
   Next
   Debug.Print RunInt, ACLDelay
End Sub
```

In fact, using the controls name makes no necessary the use their group membership...

I will leave my office  now. If something not clear, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications. I will clarify them when I will be at home.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I went with the tried and true IF statement for simplest although not the most effective.

Comment: @Hareborn I do not use VBA in PowerPoint. I tried finding a way to 'extract' the necessary object and I just played with VBA. I have a question: Didn't the line `myDocument.Shapes.GroupName` raise an error? Shapes shouldn't have a `GroupName` property... Only an Option Button object should have it, theoretically. Does the Shapes collection has such a (hidden) property in PowerPoint? **You can use each Option Button `Click` event to give the necessary value in the moment when its value is changed in `True`** and just use them when needed... This should be the most efficient way of handling them

Comment: Yes, it does have the property of "GroupName" but I could not find a way to access it. Every attempt returned "RunTime Error 438" "The object does not support this property or method". Side question, I don't remember how to mark code in the comments anymore, I haven't been on here in years.

Comment: This error 'said' exactly that it does not have it...  I mean 'Sheets' collection. It belongs only to the specific object, in the way you can see in the posted code. Now I am closing my laptop...

Comment: The GroupName property does exist as that is what I used in the properties window in VBA to assign the option buttons to their specific groups. In code you can also assign and alter the GroupName. I just could not find a way to query the GroupName to find out what button in the group was active.

Comment: @Hareborn I'm afraid we are talking about different things... Of course, `GroupName` property exists, **but only for the Option Button Object**. It does not exist for `Sheets` collection in construction `myDocument.Shapes.GroupName`. What does `Debug.Print myDocument.Shapes.GroupName` return in Immediate Window? The error  "The object does not support this property or method" means exactly what I'm saying. But, what about using the Option Button `Click` event to set the necessary variables value?

Answer (score 0):

As a starter for 10 you need to reorganise the Select construct for the option groups.

```
Select Case MyDocument.Shapes.Groupname

    Case OptionGroup1


    Case optionGroup2


    Case OptionGroup3




End Select
```

The above construct will work if 'MyDocument.Shapes.Groupname, OptionaGroup1,2,3' all yeild strings which can be compared.  To workout what happens in each case clause you need to provide the information requested in my comment above.  I'll update this answer when you do so.

Comment: Did you test this approach? The shapes property does not have such a `Groupname` property...

Comment: @FaneDuru Which bit of 'The above construct will work if 'MyDocument.Shapes.Groupname, OptionaGroup1,2,3' all yeild strings which can be compared. ' did you not understand.

Comment: The construction `MyDocument.Shapes.Groupname` will raise an error because, as I suggested, `Groupname` does not exist between `MyDocument.Shapes` properties. That's why I asked if you tested it. You maybe have a nicer PowerPoint installation...

Comment: @FaneDuru To make it simpler, which bit of 'If' don't you understand.

Comment: What I am building is a 3D animated timing test program for a conveyer system to determine run time optimization. The system has 4 types of user inputs to alter the speed of the different sections of the conveyer. Each user input section has four options for speed control, meaning 4 section with 4 options. Each of the 4 sections also has 3 animated independently moving sections that are controlled by the user input speed. The 3 option button groups listed above are independent of each other and have 4 choices for speed inputs

Comment: I am looking for the simplest process to determine which of the four option buttons in a group is selected so I can create a global variable to use throughout the entirety of the program. I have to admit that although I have a good knowledge of Excel VBA, I have little experience with PowerPoint VBA as they use vastly different syntax for the same functionality. I have already accomplished this with simple "if" statements to determine which option button shows "True" but with the entirety of the program there are to many moving parts.

Comment: The visual aspect of the program on slide 1 are lagging behind the code execution speed and causing the graphics to not sync correctly. I need to trim the code down to it's simplest concept to try to counter the lag. I forgot to mention that as the program is running the user can change the speed of the different section through the option buttons to increase the optimization of the conveyer. I need a fast, efficient way to alter the variables without increasing the graphics lag.

Comment: I clearly asked you "Did you test this approach?". You did not answer anything. Then, I tried explaining why `MyDocument.Shapes.Groupname` will raise an error. If you are not able to understand my questions, please read my comments again. I do not think I am the one who needs to clarify anything. I wish you a good day/evening!

Comment: FaneDuru, I'm unsure of why you responded in this manor. I was giving further clarification to both you and @freeflow on what the code is used for. I have tried your suggestion above and also tried a trimmed version of "If OptionButton.value = True Then ACLDelay = 2", both work but I have opted not to use them because it is causing a lag that I am trying to eliminate.  With multiple subs running concurrently and trying to  determine and passing a new variable during operation is causing the graphic to skip steps that the code has already processed. I am trying to find a code simplest version.

Comment: @Hareborn Commenting here it should be obvious that I answered to the user placing the answer. I asked him some questions and he answered with questions, too. Then, if you comment here and need me to be notified, you should tag me. The user placing the answer will be tagged anyhow. In order to be notified, you should comment below my answer (without tagging) or below your question, but a tag should be needed... It happened to come here when intended to close the page. Of course, you should use the most convenient variant/version.

Answer (score 0):

I went with simple IF statements to solve my issue. This is not bar far the most effective method but works for now.

```
If OptionButtonACL1s.Value = True Then
    ACLDelay = 1
End If
If OptionButtonACL2s.Value = True Then
    ACLDelay = 2
End If
If OptionButtonACL3s.Value = True Then
    ACLDelay = 3
End If
If OptionButtonACLr.Value = True Then
    ACLDelay = Int((10 * Rnd) + 1)
End If

If OptionButtonMOD5s.Value = True Then
    MODDelay = 0.5
End If
If OptionButtonMOD1s.Value = True Then
    MODDelay = 1
End If
If OptionButtonMOD15.Value = True Then
    MODDelay = 1.5
End If
If OptionButtonMOD2s.Value = True Then
    MODDelay = 2
End If

If OptionButtonRT5m.Value = True Then
    RunInt = 5
End If
If OptionButtonRT15m.Value = True Then
    RunInt = 15
End If
If OptionButtonRT30m.Value = True Then
    RunInt = 30
End If
If OptionButtonRT1h.Value = True Then
    RunInt = 60
End If
```